# CSS minmax(): prioritize max value

Tags: css, grid, css-grid, minmax

> **minmax:**
>   If max < min, then max is ignored and minmax(min,max) is treated as min..

I want to do something like

```
grid-template-columns: 1fr minmax(50%, 70vmin) 1fr;
```

I don't want the column to exceed `70vmin`. According to specification, in situations where `70vmin` happens to be less than `50%`, it chooses the `50%` as the column size, which I don't want. Is it possible to somehow invert this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is the combination of `width`/`max-width` like this:

```
width:50%;
max-width:70vmin;
```

- If `70vmin > 50%` then we will have at least `50%` (our min boundary) and we will not exceed `70vmin`
- if `70vmin < 50%` then we will have a width equal to 70vmin (our max
  boundary that suppress the min one)

You can achieve this using a simple div and `margin:auto`. No need for grid:

```css
.grid-item {
  max-width: 70vmin;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  margin:auto;
  background: red;
};
```

```html
 <div class="grid-item"></div>
```

In the above example we fixed the width to 50% so technically it won't be bigger. In case you want to have bigger than 50% when `70vmin` is also bigger you can try the following combination:

```css
.grid-container {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  margin:20px 0;
}

.grid-item {
  max-width: 70vmin;
  flex-basis:50%;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item"> some text</div>
</div>

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item"> some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text</div>
</div>
```

We set the initial width using flex-basis to be at least `50%`, we fix the `max-width` and the content can make the element to grow between `50%` and `70vmin`

Answer (score 2):

That's what `minmax()` does, by definition. So try another approach.

Instead of this:

```
grid-container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr minmax(50%, 70vmin) 1fr
}
```

Consider this:

```
grid-container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr
}

grid-item {
    max-width: 70vmin;
    min-width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: If I am not wrong `min-width` is *more powerful* than `max-width` so if 70vmin is lower than 50%, 50% will also apply here: https://jsfiddle.net/n6gyrzb4/

Answer (score 1):

Try one of the following simpler solutions:

```
grid-template-columns: 1fr minmax(min(50%, 70vmin), 70vmin) 1fr;
```

Or in the non-grid case:

```
.class {
  min-width: min(50%, 70vmin);
  max-width: 70vmin;
}
```

It explicitly makes sure the min value is never bigger than the max value using the `min()` function. And still allows the content to set its width to something in between when possible.